# I entered Hungary as a Schengen visitor, but left on a Temp. Residence Permit. When can I return as a Schengen visitor?

Tags: schengen, europe, eu, hungary, canadian-residents

I entered Hungary earlier this year (mid April), and spent my 90 days there. Just before my time was up, I applied and was approved for a temp. residence permit - which would allow me to stay (not work) until mid November.

My question: To return to Hungary, do I need to wait a full 90 days from when my RP expired, 90 days from the day I actually exited Hungary, or 90 days from the date my initial 90 days (on the schengen stamp) would expire?

Feel free to ask me to clarify anything. To note, it is important I do go back to Hungary, because my partner is there and he's recovering from an injury. We're unmarried. We obviously will need to sort out a better system.

Additional info: I'm a Canadian citizen, and I have an active working holiday visa for Ireland. We lived there and in the UK together. We're still confused whether Hungary recognizes us as common-law, therefore myself as a family member. The immigration there were not very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Time spent in Hungary on a Hungarian residence permit does not count towards the 90/180 rule.  Time spent in other Schengen countries does count, but that is not generally enforced.  The rest of this answer assumes that you haven't been in any other Schengen countries.

The 90 day limit will be fully reset on the 91st day of your residence permit's validity.  Therefore, because the permit is valid for longer than 91 days (July to November), you should be able to spend 90 days in the Schengen area immediately after it expires.